# Updating Names-Collection in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to implement a validation for the named ranges in a given workbook.

I first create a list of the named ranges when the workbook is first opened.

Then, when a macro is called, I check if all the named ranges are still in the workbook and use the [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.name.validworkbookparameter) `Name.ValidWorkbookParameter` to check, if the named Range is still valid.
I noticed however, when I overwrite a named range (the value is then e.g. `#REF`) and set the named Range back to its intended value, then the property `Name.ValidWorkbookParameter` still returns `False`. Is there a way to update the `Names`-Collection, so the properties are shown correctly?

**EDIT**

```vb
Function checkNamedRanges()
    Dim nm As Name
    
    For Each nm In Names
        Debug.Print nm.ValidWorkbookParameter
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Please update the question to include the code you've currently got. As I understand it, you're just trying to check if a given list of named ranges exist in the workbook?

Comment: @JoshEller When i run the function I get `True`-Statements for all the named ranges. But when I overwrite a named Range its property `ValidWorkbookParameter` returns False. When I manually correct the named Range back to its intended Value, the property `ValidWorkbookParameter` still returns False. I'm wondering if it is possible to update the property somehow.